# Two R functions for Bayesian updating with different output

Tags: r, bayesian, function

Basically, I have made two posterior (`ps`) updating R functions; `auto1` and `auto2`. That is, `ps` from one set of `n` and `s` becomes prior (`pr`) for the new set of `n` and `s`.

But it seems the two functions produce different posteriors, I'm wondering which function is accurate; `auto1` or `auto2`?

```
auto1 <- function(n, s, top = 5){

  props <- seq(0, 1, 1e-4)
    pr <- dbeta(props, 1, 1)
    pr <- 1e4 * pr / sum(pr)
plot(pr~props, ylim = c(0, top*length(n)), type = "l", yaxt = "n", ylab = NA)

for(i in 1:length(n)) {
ps <- dbinom(s[i], n[i], props) * pr
ps <- 1e4 * ps / sum(ps)
lines((ps+i+1)~props, col = i +1)
pr <- ps
  }
}
auto1(n = c(100, 90, 120), s = c(55, 60, 80), top = 7)
```

#=============================================================

```
auto2 <- function(n, s, top = 2.5){

  U <- function(x) dbeta(x, 1, 1)
  props <- seq(0, 1, 1e-4)
  pr <- U(props)

plot(pr~props, ylim = c(0, top*length(n)), type = "l", lty = 2, yaxt = "n", ylab = NA)

for(i in 1:length(n)) {

lk <- function(x) dbinom(s[i], n[i], x)
k <- integrate(function(x) U(x)*lk(x), 0, 1)[[1]]
ps <- function(x) U(x)*lk(x)/k

lines((ps(props)+i+1)~props, col = i +1)
pr <- ps
   }
}
auto2(n = c(100, 90, 120), s = c(55, 60, 80), top = 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in `auto2` you are never actually using `pr` inside the for-loop, you are always referring back to `U(x)`, which is the uniform prior.  So... no updating is occurring *across* observations, only the uniform prior is being updated with the *single* observation indexed by `i`.

Examine this modification with care:

```
auto2 <- function(n, s, top = 2.5){

   prior <- function(new_x, x, y) approx(x, y=y, xout=new_x)$y
   props <- seq(0, 1, 1e-4)
   pr <- dbeta(props,1,1)

   plot(pr~props, ylim = c(0, top*length(n)), type = "l", lty = 2, yaxt = "n", ylab = NA)

   for(i in 1:length(n)) {

      lk <- function(x) dbinom(s[i], n[i], x)
      k <- integrate(function(x) prior(x,props,pr)*lk(x), 0, 1)[[1]]
      ps <- function(x) prior(x,props,pr)*lk(x)/k

      lines((ps(props)+i+1)~props, col = i +1)
      pr <- ps(props)
   }
}
auto2(n = c(100, 90, 120), s = c(55, 60, 80), top = 7)
```

`approx` does linear interpolation between the values passed to it.  It provides a functional version of the prior, instead of just the list of values provided in `auto1`.  The functional version is based on the x-values, in this case `props`, and the values of the distribution function, stored in `pr`, but, because it's a function, can be integrated.

At every iteration / value of `i` we update the vector `pr`, which acts to update the values returned from `prior` with the just-formed posterior.  You will note that the two sets of curves are identical now!

Edit in response to a follow-up question:

You can also get confidence intervals etc. from the two functions.  Consider `auto1`; edit it so it returns `list(pr=pr, props=props)`.  We can then find a confidence interval using the following function:

```
res <- auto1(n = c(100, 90, 120), s = c(55, 60, 80), top = 7)

ci_1 <- function(res, alpha) {
       res$cdf <- cumsum(res$pr)
       list(lower=res$props[max(which(res$cdf<alpha))],
            upper=res$props[min(which(res$cdf>(1-alpha)))])   
}
```

which in this case results in:

```
> ci_1(res, alpha=0.05)
$lower
[1] 0.504

$upper
[1] 0.5236
```

Note that this is not the purist's confidence interval, although it is one; the purist's CI would be the shortest of all confidence intervals that contain, in this case, 95% of the posterior mass.  That's not hard to find, but in the case of nearly symmetric posteriors, the two will be very similar.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I've extended my answer to cover your question.

Comment: Right, you'd need to rerun the function to get a new posterior, it's not self-contained.  But you could merge the two - make the last step of `auto1` call `ci_1`, for example, and return the result.

Comment: I just ran into an error in `auto2`. If you restrict your prior to a specific range like: $.6~to~.8$, than the function fails.  to produce the correct posterior? Is their a fix for that?

Comment: I mean if you use `props <-  seq(.6, .8, 1e-4)` and even if you correct the integrals bounds to `.6` and `.8` the correct posterior is not given?